# Test to see if key independent variable is significant across time

Tags: panel-data, difference-in-difference

I am working with panel data and using OLS.  Specifically, I am examining congressmen across multiple congresses.  I am including congress-specific fixed effects to control for issues such as polarization and economic growth.  For my key independent variable (it is significant in the pooled data), it was suggested there could be a selection bias because variables that are absorbed by the fixed-effects (polarization) could be influencing my key independent variable.  In other words, my key independent variable may not be significant across time and a few units could be driving the results.

Aside from arbitrarily dividing my data by time periods, is their a way to see if my independent variable is significant across all congresses?  Someone recommended difference-in-differences.  Would this account for this bias?  Can you use DiD with a continuous independent variable and with more than two time periods?  If anyone could point me to any literature, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can use a DiD framework with a continuous treatment variable and more than two time periods.

I don´t understood your problem very well, you have to clarify the treatment variable.

In the chapter 5 of the Mostly Harmless Econometrics there is some examples of DiD with continuous treatment.

One example is this paper:  [Zabel and Dalton, 2011](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016604621100072X)

Comment: Thanks!  Wooldridge (2012) described DiD as only two time periods and I was confused.  That paper you cited will get me started in the right direction.